# Can I make indent over many line on overleaf in \newtheorem?

Tags: math-mode, indentation, alignment, pseudocode

I like to make it so that when I used \begin{pf} everything in the area is indented in a bit and when \end{pf} the text after is indented back out again, and if there are others inside it is indented more (kind of like pseudocode) like this [image: how i want look]
So far I have

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{enumerate}

\newtheorem*{pf}{\textcolor{Emerald}{Proof}}
\newtheorem*{remark}{\textcolor{WildStrawberry}{Remark}}
\newtheorem*{note}{\textcolor{Cyan}{Note}}
\newtheorem*{ex}{\textcolor{Mulberry}{Example}}

\newtheorem{theorem}{\textcolor{OliveGreen}{Theorem}}[section]
```

[image]

Am I on the right track? Can I make such indentation?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Pleae -- as usual here -- make your given code snippet compilable! Then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...